# Changing a member function in a derived class in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

`shape`is defined as the base class. Classes `rectangle` and `circle` are classes derived from the class `shape`. I'm trying to create a new derived class `car` which inherits from both `circle`and `rectangle`. Any instantiation of `class` will be a rectangle and two circles below the rectangle.
However, I couldn't figure out how to redefine `set_color()` so that I can set distinct colors for the rectangle and wheels `circle`. Thanks in advance.

```
    !pip install calysto

from calysto.graphics import *
from calysto.display import display, clear_output
import time
import math

CANVAS_240 = Canvas(size=(400, 400))

class shape:

  color = None
  x = None
  y = None
 
  def set_color(self, red, green, blue):
    self.color = (red, green, blue)
 
  def move_to(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def move_on_line(self, x_fin, y_fin, count_of_steps):
    delta_x = (x_fin - self.x)/count_of_steps
    delta_y = (y_fin - self.y)/count_of_steps
    while self.x != x_fin and self.y != y_fin:
      shape_has_color = self.color 
      self.set_color(255,255,255)
      self.draw()
      self.color = shape_has_color
      self.move_to(self.x+delta_x,self.y+delta_y)
      self.draw()

  def displace(self, delta_x, delta_y):
    shape_has_color = self.color
    self.set_color(255, 255, 255) # that is white. i.e. the background color
    self.draw()
    self.color = shape_has_color
    self.move_to(self.x+delta_x, self.y+delta_y)
    self.draw()

  def __str__(self):
    return "shape object: color=%s coordinates=%s" % (self.color, (self.x, self.y))

  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def displace(self, delta_x, delta_y):
    shape_has_color = self.color
    self.set_color(255, 255, 255) # that is white. i.e. the background color
    self.draw()
    self.color = shape_has_color
    self.move_to(self.x+delta_x, self.y+delta_y)
    self.draw()

class circle(shape):

  radius = None

  def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.radius = radius
    self.set_color(255, 0, 0)
     
  def draw(self):
    c = Circle((self.x, self.y), self.radius)
    c.fill(Color(self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2]))
    c.noStroke()
    clear_output(wait=True)
    c.draw(CANVAS_240)
    display(CANVAS_240)
    
    
    
class rectangle(shape):

  width = None
  height = None

  def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.set_color(255, 0, 0)
     
  def draw(self):
    rb = (self.x+self.width, self.y)
    ru = (self.x+self.width, self.y+self.height)
    lu = (self.x, self.y+self.height)
    lb = (self.x, self.y)
    r = Polygon([lb,rb,ru,lu])
    r.fill(Color(self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2]))
    r.noStroke()
    clear_output(wait=True)
    r.draw(CANVAS_240)
    display(CANVAS_240)

class triangle(shape):
  dx2 = None
  dy2 = None
  dx3 = None
  dy3 = None

  def __init__(self, x,y,dx2,dy2,dx3,dy3):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.dx2 = dx2
    self.dy2 = dy2
    self.dx3 = dx3
    self.dy3 = dy3
    self.set_color(255,0,0)
  
  def draw(self):
    fi = (self.x,self.y)
    se = (self.x + self.dx2,self.y+self.dy2)
    th = (self.x+self.dx3,self.y+self.dy3)
    t = Polygon([fi,se,th])
    t.fill(Color(self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2]))
    t.noStroke()
    clear_output(wait=True)
    t.draw(CANVAS_240)
    display(CANVAS_240)

class car(rectangle,circle):
  width = None
  height = None
  radius = None

  def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, radius):
    rectangle.__init__(self,x,y,width,height)
    circle.__init__(self,x,y,radius)
    self.set_color(255,0,0)


  def draw(self):
    rb = (self.x+self.width, self.y)
    ru = (self.x+self.width, self.y + self.height)
    lb = (self.x,self.y)
    lu = (self.x,self.y+self.height)
    r = Polygon([lb,rb,ru,lu])
    w1 = Circle((self.x, self.y+self.height), self.radius)
    w2 = Circle((self.x+self.width, self.y+self.height), self.radius)
    r.fill(Color(self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2]))
    r.noStroke()
    w1.fill(Color(self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2]))
    w1.noStroke()
    w2.fill(Color(self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2]))
    w2.noStroke()
    clear_output(wait=True)
    r.draw(CANVAS_240)
    w1.draw(CANVAS_240)
    w2.draw(CANVAS_240)
    display(CANVAS_240)
```

Comment: `set_color` needs to call `circle.set_color` and `rectangle.set_color` explicitly. Besides, this does not look like a good use of (multiple) inheritance, consider using composition instead.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem,it would be more efficient if composition is used instead of inheritance.Composition allows to reuse the implementation of the components it contains.The composite class(newly formed class) doesn’t inherit the component class interface, but it can use its implementation.In this case,object of **car** class is the combination of two objects of **circle** class and one object of **rectangle** class,but not a derived object of any of them.So it can be created like:

```py
class car:
   def __init__(self,body,wheel):
      self.body=body
      self.wheel=wheel
#Here body is an object of **rectangle** class and wheel is an object of **circle** class
      #color of wheel and body can be independently set as
   def set_color(self,body_color,wheel_color):
      self.wheel.set_color(wheel_color)
      self.body.set_color(body_color)
#Accordingly draw method will change
```